# Отступ под картинкой

Tags: html, css

Откуда берётся пробел под картинкой, что это за отступ?

[image: img]

http://jsfiddle.net/9qJBT/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="header">
<a href="#"><img src="http://s018.radikal.ru/i510/1407/ee/17c78875e0a6.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
background: #EEEEEE;
}

#header {
width: 900px;
background: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Если задать блоку `#header` ширину 48 как у картинки, то отступ естественно пропадает.

Comment: `<img>`, по умолчанию - строчный (текстовой) элемент со всеми вытекающими

http://jsfiddle.net/9qJBT/1/

Answer (score 1):

Надо у картинки прописать display: block  и будет вам счастье

Answer (score 0):

Можно прописать для всех изображений:

```
img {display:block;position:relative;}
```